# PHP prepare statement Notice: Only variables should be passed by reference

Tags: php, mysql

my first time writing prepared statement

this code is checking your late in every 3 hours then inserting the time interval into db

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Hong_Kong');
$now = new DateTime();

if ($now->format("H:i") > "22:00") {
$deadline = DateTime::createFromFormat("H:i", "22:00");
$diff = $now->diff($deadline);
echo "You are ".$diff->h." hours and ".$diff->i." minutes late";

} else if ($now->format("H:i") > "19:00") {
$deadline = DateTime::createFromFormat("H:i", "19:00");
$diff = $now->diff($deadline);
echo "You are ".$diff->h." hours and ".$diff->i." minutes late";

} else if ($now->format("H:i") > "16:00") {
$deadline = DateTime::createFromFormat("H:i", "16:00");
$diff = $now->diff($deadline);
echo "You are ".$diff->h." hours and ".$diff->i." minutes late";

} else if ($now->format("H:i") > "13:00") {
$deadline = DateTime::createFromFormat("H:i", "13:00");
$diff = $now->diff($deadline);
echo "You are ".$diff->h." hours and ".$diff->i." minutes late";

} else if ($now->format("H:i") > "10:00") {
$deadline = DateTime::createFromFormat("H:i", "10:00");
$diff = $now->diff($deadline);
echo "You are ".$diff->h." hours and ".$diff->i." minutes late";

} else if ($now->format("H:i") > "07:00") {
$deadline = DateTime::createFromFormat("H:i", "07:00");
$diff = $now->diff($deadline);
echo "You are ".$diff->h." hours and ".$diff->i." minutes late";
}

$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO time_in (e_id, login, late, date_in)
 VALUES (?, ?, ?,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)");

$stmt->bind_param("sss", $e_id, $login, $diff->format('%H:%i'));

$e_id = "id is unavailable"; // changing to $_POST in the future
$login = "1";

$status = $stmt->execute();

if(!$status) {
    echo $stmt->error;    
    exit;
}
echo "success";

}
```

and im getting this

> Notice: Only variables should be passed by reference

at this line `$stmt->bind_param("sss", $e_id, $login, $diff->format('%H:%i'))`

the code working perfectly but im getting that notice
please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you must pass actual variables to bind_param, since `$diff->format('%H:%i')` is not a variable but rather the output of a function, it doesn't like that.

You will need to assign this to a variable first then pass it in. i.e

```
$diffFormat = $diff->format('%H:%i');

$stmt->bind_param("sss", $e_id, $login, $diffFormat);
```